# How can I make custom 2D polygon in Unity with collision detection?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, polygon

I am learning Unity and I want to make a little game where the user controls a tank and she can shot with it. My plan is when the missile hit the terrain, it makes a hole in that, like in the old school Worms. My first idea was to make the terrain as a textured polygon and when a collision happens, change the polygon structure. Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: I don't know if this is something easier in the 2D world. Here is the [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/boolean-subtraction-operations-on-mesh.85713/) to the Unity forum about a similar problem in 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little trick with a 3D mesh. If you are using orthogonal camera the Z axis won't be visible and you will be able to add mesh collider. If you still want to do custom things with that mesh like changing shape there are assets on the store:
http://u3d.as/content/chris-west/mega-fiers/1Qa

Or

When a missle hits terrain change you terrain texture pixels alpha channel to 0 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html

Then use raycasts to check if alpha channel != 0 for moving.